# Flush Redis AWS ElastiCache with Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache

I am using Laravel 5.5 in my application hosted by AWS; for caching I'm using Redis on ElastiCache. After some research I was able to configure it (using cluster), it works fine however Laravel is unable to flush in redis-cluster:

```
Cannot use 'FLUSHDB' with redis-cluster
```

After some digging I learned there is a bug in Laravel that does not allow flush in redis-cluster. I'm wondering: is there a way to use Redis in ElastiCache in a "non-cluster" way?

When I created the Redis instance I did not select the `Cluster Mode enabled` but apparently it still create as cluster.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Clusters, configure your `config/database.php` file such that there's no `clusters` key in the redis connection

Check out the docs to learn how: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/redis#configuration